# How to move a rectangle on key press in sdl2 using a method

Tags: c++, sdl

I am using SDL library to create a pong game. I am at the point where I want the paddle to move up and down when the letter w is pressed on the keyboard. I am trying to move the rectangle when w is pressed. but it won't work. It worked before but it just keeps painting over the renderer instead of moving the whole rectangle.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include<SDL.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
Uint32 white;
Uint32 black;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;
const int HEIGHT = 700;
const int WIDTH = 800;
const int padH = 95;
const int padW = 25;
SDL_Event e;
SDL_Rect player;
SDL_Rect player2;
SDL_Rect Ball;
void init() 
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Pong",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,WIDTH,HEIGHT,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    white = SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 255, 255);
    black= SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0,0,0);
    player.h = padH;
    player.w = padW;
    player2.h = padH;
    player2.w = padW;

    player.x = 20;
    player.y = HEIGHT / 2;
    player2.x = WIDTH-40;
    player2.y = HEIGHT / 2;
    Ball.h = 20;
    Ball.w = 20;
    Ball.x = WIDTH / 2;
    Ball.y = HEIGHT / 2;


}

void draw() 
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,0,255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,255,255,255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &Ball);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player2);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);


}

void gamelogic()
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) !=0) 

    {
        if (e.type = SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_w:
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player);
                player.y = player.y + 1;

            }

        }

    }
}
int main(int arg, char*argv[]) {
    bool done = true;

    init();
    draw();
    gamelogic();
    while (done) 
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&e);
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            done = false;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

when I put the key press in the while loop it just keeps painting instead of moving the rectangle and brushing it over

Answer (score 0):

Your main loop is basically non-existent - it just pumps event queue and exits when last window is closed (or any time before that, because you never check if there was event but still react to it - it could be anything). Main loop should check events, react to events, and redraw, on each iteration. You don't need to draw anything in event handling code, and `if (e.type = SDL_KEYDOWN)` is assignment, not comparison - I suggest enabling compiler warnings.

To sum it up, complete example (with big room for improvement left):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
Uint32 white;
Uint32 black;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;
const int HEIGHT = 700;
const int WIDTH = 800;
const int padH = 95;
const int padW = 25;
SDL_Event e;
SDL_Rect player;
SDL_Rect player2;
SDL_Rect Ball;
bool done = false;

void init() 
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Pong",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,WIDTH,HEIGHT,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    white = SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 255, 255);
    black= SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0,0,0);
    player.h = padH;
    player.w = padW;
    player2.h = padH;
    player2.w = padW;

    player.x = 20;
    player.y = HEIGHT / 2;
    player2.x = WIDTH-40;
    player2.y = HEIGHT / 2;
    Ball.h = 20;
    Ball.w = 20;
    Ball.x = WIDTH / 2;
    Ball.y = HEIGHT / 2;
}

void draw() 
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,0,255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,255,255,255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &Ball);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player2);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void gamelogic()
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) !=0) 
    {
        if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_w:
                player.y = player.y + 1;

            }
        }
        else if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            done = true;
        }
    }
}

int main(int arg, char*argv[]) {
    init();

    while (!done)
    {
        gamelogic();
        draw();
    }

    return 0;
}
```